# How to check if a string is alphanumeric?

Tags: string, julia, alphanumeric

I can use `occursin` function, but its `haystack` argument cannot be a regular expression, which means I have to pass the entire alphanumeric string to it. Is there a neat way of doing this in Julia?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but its `haystack` argument cannot be a regular expression, which means I have to pass the entire alphanumeric string to it.

If you mean its `needle` argument, it *can* be a Regex, for eg.:

```
julia> occursin(r"^[[:alnum:]]*$", "adf24asg24y")
true

julia> occursin(r"^[[:alnum:]]*$", "adf24asg2_4y")
false
```

This checks that the given `haystack` string is alphanumeric using Unicode-aware character class
`[[:alnum:]]` which you can think of as equivalent to `[a-zA-Z\d]`, extended to non-English characters too. (As always with Unicode, a "perfect" solution involves more work and complication, but this takes you most of the way.)

If you do mean you want the `haystack` argument to be a Regex, it's not clear why you'd want that here, and also why "I have to pass the entire alphanumeric string to it" is a bad thing.

Comment: You can actually use `[:alnum:]` in place of `[:alpha:][:digit:]`.

Comment: I'd forgotten about that one, thank you. Edited the answer to incorporate `:alnum:` now.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure your assumption about `occursin` is correct:

```
julia> occursin(r"[a-zA-z]", "ABC123")
true

julia> occursin(r"[a-zA-z]", "123")
false
```

Answer (score 1):

As has been noted, you can indeed use regexes with `occursin`, and it works well. But you can also roll your own version, quite simply:

```
isalphanumeric(c::AbstractChar) = isletter(c) || ('0' <= c <= '9')
isalphanumeric(str::AbstractString) = all(isalphanumeric, str)
```

Comment: Yes, I actually did this. Thank you.